# SSRS RDL Export to PDF by C#

Tags: c#, pdf, reporting-services, pdf-generation

We are doing an SSRS project and we need to test the reports for different parameters.

Hence I want to create an application which will automatically convert rdl(SSRS) to pdf by using the parameters.

Thanks,
 Kiran

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`ReportExecutionService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc282506.aspx) class. If you have any report parameters to set, use [`SetExecutionParameters()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.setexecutionparameters.aspx) and [`Render()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx) with `Format=PDF`. Code samples at the bottom of the `Render` method page.